# How do I refer to a value from a previous iteration?

Tags: python

For different iterations of x, I'm trying to subtract the previous value from the current value and stop the loop if the difference between them is small enough (maybe 0.0001) or something.

Tried several things such as referring to the x as a function of n, but not really sure on how to do that.

```
y=int(input('Enter number for cubed root:'))
x=1
N=0
D=0

while N < 50:
    x=1/3*(2*(x) + y/(x**2))
    N=N+1
    print('Estimation:',x)
    print()

    if x(N))==x(N+1):
        print('Difference negligible')
        break
```

Comment: Store it in another variable. e.g. `previousx`

Comment: You can't magically refer to a value from the previous iteration. You should create another variable to keep track of this value. [why is there a huge "Delete" link next to my comment? I don't like that, I prefer the tiny "x" button...]

Comment: BTW, you have an extra, unmatched parenthesis: `x(N))`

Comment: @ForceBru https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379654/delete-button-showing-up-as-the-word-delete-rather-than-the-normal-x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use a different variable to hold the value of the last loop iteration.

Maybe this works for you:

```
previous_x = None
while N < 50:
    ...

    if previous_x is not None:
        if abs(x - previous_x) < 0.0001:
            print('Difference negligible')
            break

    previous_x = x
```

Comment: Perfect, got what I was looking for, although I must admit I'm slightly puzzled as to why the previous_x = x comes in the last line?

Comment: @ColinK otherwise, if you set it before, the difference will be 0 since it's then the exact same value

Comment: @ColinK on the last line you change the value of `previous_x` to the value of the current `x`; in the next iteration `x` will change, but `previous_x` will stay the same (until the end of the iteration). If you change `previous_x` any sooner, the comparisson to the current `x` will not be possible.

Comment: Making  X a default value at the beginning will make the if is not none control obsolete and speed up the code. Just make sure that your default value does not affect your calculation

Answer (score 4):

You can build your own iterator function which returns the current and the next value. Something like the following should work:

```
def take_current_and_next(it):
    last = None
    for current in it:
        if last is not None:
            yield last, current
        last = current

values = list(range(6))

for current, next_ in take_current_and_next(values):
    print(current, next_)
```

which gives:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
```

The above code would not work as expected, if your iterator can return None values. The following code should also handle "None"-values:

```
def take_current_and_next(it):
    it = iter(it)
    current = next(it)
    for next_ in it:
        yield current, next_
        current = next_
```